# how to distribute the entries of a matrix in a larger one using matrix products

Tags: r, algorithm, linear-algebra

Given the matrix A, where A is

```
x_11  x_12  x_13 
x_21  x_22  x_23
x_31  x_32  x_33
x_41  x_42  x_43
```

how can I efficiently create this second matrix using matrix products?

```
x_11    0   0   x_21    0   0   x_31    0   0   x_41    0   0
0   x_12    0   0   x_22    0   0   x_32    0   0   x_42    0
0   0   x_13    0   0   x_23    0   0   x_33    0   0   x_43
```

Comment: Here is a package that creates diagnal matrices.  Maybe its function could be used in apply or with reshape or cbind.  http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/docs/openmx/latest/_static/rdoc/vec2diag.html  Although that might not be the most efficient approach.

Comment: Where does the linear algebra come in?

Comment: @HongOoi It's probably a homework question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your original matrix is `m`:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow=4)
```

Now, some juggling of `row` and `col`:

```
m2 <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=length(m))
m2[((col(m2) - 1) %% 3 + 1) == row(m2)] <- m
m2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text='11  12  13 
21  22  23
31  32  33
41  42  43'))

do.call(cbind, lapply(split(m, seq(nrow(m))), diag))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
# [1,]   11    0    0   21    0    0   31    0    0    41     0     0
# [2,]    0   12    0    0   22    0    0   32    0     0    42     0
# [3,]    0    0   13    0    0   23    0    0   33     0     0    43
```